# css autoprefixer with webpack

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer, postcss

I have been trying to configure webpack with LESS and Autoprefixer, but autoprefixer does not seem to work. My css or less files are not autoprefixed. Example:
`display: flex` stays `display: flex`

I have put my webpack config below:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: "./index.jsx"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader")
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!postcss-loader")
      }

    ],
    postcss: function () {
      return [autoprefixer];
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(banner),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    stats: 'warnings-only',
  }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So found the problem. Silly me, the postcss block needs to be directly under the webpack config, I had put it in modules block. My Bad.

EDIT: this is how it should have been:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    ...
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer];
    }
    ...
};
```

So instead of putting it inside the modules block, I had to put it directly under the main block as shown above.

Answer (score 19):

> As written in [Autoprefixer documentation](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), "Autoprefixer uses Browserslist"
>
> As per the [Browserslist documentation](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries), it is recommended to place the browserslist in `package.json`.

So here is another way to **use autoprefixer with webpack**:

install postcss-loader and autoprefixer:

`npm i -D postcss-loader autoprefixer`

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/, 
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },
    { 
      test: /\.css$/, 
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] 
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

> As per [postcss documentation](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#config-cascade), the `postcss-loader` should be placed after `css-loader` and `style-loader`, **but before** other preprocessor loaders like e.g `sass|less|stylus-loader`, if you use any.

**`package.json`**

```
"postcss": {
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {}
  }
},
"browserslist": [
  "last 2 version",
  "not dead",
  "iOS >= 9"
]
```

In this way, you don't need a `postcss.config.js` file.

Comment: looks like you need another package to not use a postcss.config.js file like that: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/252#issuecomment-306933122

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation _and_ for taking time to provide the links to the documentation!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set up postcss in your webpack config for older browser versions.

Default for autoprefixer is last 2 versions of browsers or browsers that have at least 5% market share.

https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers

```
  postcss: [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 3 versions', '> 1%']
    })
  ],
```

It says that you are supporting last 3 versions of browsers or browsers that have at least 1% market share.

Comment: it's not thorwing any errors `Hash: d630b9d8e940465f3b07
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 1772ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  708 kB       0  [emitted]  bundle
bundle.js.map  816 kB       0  [emitted]  bundle
    + 171 hidden modules`

Comment: I think it's worth saying that webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with **Webpack 2.x.x** and custom properties are no longer allowed in configuration. I found a solution on this other S.O post: [Using auto prefixer with postcss in webpack 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761473/using-autoprefixer-with-postcss-in-webpack-2-x). In case for some unknown reason this link would lead to a 404 I  compile the most relevant answers here:

**Webpack 2.x.x** introduced **webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin()** plugin where you need to define all the loader option plugins. Like, autoprefixer is a plugin for postcss-loader. So, it has to go here.
New config should look like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 
      'postcss-loader']
    }
  ]
},

plugins: [
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      postcss: [
        autoprefixer(),
      ]
    }
  })
],
```

This worked for me, but as mentioned by Kreig there is no need for LoaderOptionsPlugin(). You can now pass options directly to the loader declaration:

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

let settings = {
/*...*/
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          /*...other loaders...*/
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: function () {
                  return [autoprefixer]
                }
              }
          }
          /*...other loaders...*/
       ]
    }]
  }         
}
/*...*/
```

Thing is I've tried the 2nd with Webpack 2.5.1 but it failed. Credits goes to Pranesh Ravi and Kreig.