# Using autoprefixer with postcss in webpack 2.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

How to use `autoprefixer` with webpack 2.x.

Previously, it used to be something like this...

```
...

module: {
  loaders: [
     {
       test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass!postcss'
     }
   ]
},
postcss: () => {
  return [autoprefixer]
},

...
```

But, it's not working anymore.

How to rewrite it to webpack@2.x.x?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Webpack 2.x.x is a killer and a build breaker

`webpack 2.x.x` introduced `webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin()` plugin where you need to define all the loader option plugins. Like, `autoprefixer` is a plugin for `postcss-loader`. So, it has to go here.

And

- `module.rules` replaces `module.loaders`
- All the loaders should have explicitly say that they are a loader. Ex.
  `loader: 'style!css'` should be `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'`

The new config will look something like this...

```
...

module: {
  rules: [
     {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']
     }
   ]
},

plugins: [
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      postcss: [
        autoprefixer(),
      ]
     }
  })
],

...
```

Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Just what I needed :)

Comment: loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader'] . This line can be written as loader: 'style!css!sass!postcss' because webpack implicity consider style-loader as style and so on...

Comment: There is no more need to use LoaderOptionsPlugin, check @kreig [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43287925/3687018)

Answer (score 26):

There is no more need to use `LoaderOptionsPlugin`. Now you can pass options directly to the loader declaration.

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

let settings = {
    /*...*/
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                /*...other loaders...*/
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: function () {
                            return [autoprefixer]
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*...other loaders...*/
            ]
        }]}         
    }
    /*...*/
};
```

In case if you need to provide specific compatibility configuration, you can pass it as argument to `autoprefixer` function:

```
options: {
    plugins: function () {
        return [autoprefixer('last 2 versions', 'ie 10')]
    }
}
```

Comment: docs for autoprefixer recommend placing the browsers list in the root level package.json so that other tools can access it if needed: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers

Answer (score 18):

As of July 20, 2017 to set up Autoprefixer with Webpack v2.4.1 I did the following:

Install necessary loaders:

```
yarn add -D postcss-loader autoprefixer style-loader sass-loader css-loader
```

create a postcss.config.js file in the root directory of your project:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
};
```

In your root level `package.json` specify browsers you want to support:

```
"browserslist": ["defaults", "not ie < 11"]
```

In your `webpack.config.js` file's `module.rules` specify your loaders with the `postcss-loader` following the `css-loader` (I'm also using `scss`):

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader' // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a <style> tag
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader' //  interprets @import and url() like import/require() and will resolve them.
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader', // postcss loader so we can use autoprefixer
        options: {
          config: {
            path: 'postcss.config.js'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
      }
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Could you clarify where to put this in your package.json?

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Here is an example package.json https://gist.github.com/clhenrick/7ee7bdc417b3128828992a1784f78b3d

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted this, as I like the outside config solution to cut down on extraneous items in the webpack config.

Answer (score 3):

Current `webpack.config.js` for using **autoprefixer** and **postcss** with **webpack** `2.1.0-beta.27`

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: { filename: 'bundle.js', publicPath: '' },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true, importLoaders: 1 } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [ { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'] } } ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'Example', template: './index.html' }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: { postcss: [ autoprefixer ] } })
  ],
}
```

**Note:** The LoaderOptionsPlugin is a 'polyfill' required in webpack `=< 2.1.0-beta.24`. I will update this answer when I work out the new syntax.

**Running it:**

Have the following relevant packages in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^6.5.4",
  "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
  "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
  "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.27",
  "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.12"
}
```

And the following relevant script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --hot"
},
```

And run it with

```
yarn install
npm run dev
```